# OdbcDataAdapter Table Names - in C

Tags: c#

We got in-house software and I'm trying to connect to it via OdbcDataAdapter. It's a in-house database as well.

I have managed to connect to Db via excel but I'm having problems in C.
I'm not sure how to phrase correctly the table names. I have managed in excel as trial and error.

String from Excel:

```
queryString = "SELECT * FROM ADI.\"kzn-57 | 600 | Survey Disabled | Realtime\"";

ADI = databasename
Table = kz - 50 | 600 | Data Disabled | Realtime
```

I'm getting errors as below:

> Unknown Table Name.

```
string connectionString = "dsn=int_db";
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        OdbcConnection connection =
           new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM ADI.\"kz-50 | 0600 | Data Disabled | Realtime\"";
        OdbcDataAdapter adapter =   
        new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

        connection.Open();                // Connection established ok
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);            // unknown tables error
        Console.WriteLine(dataSet.GetXml());
```

Comment: in your connection string try to define the database=ADI; and then in your querystring should be, `SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE...` like a normal sql. Start with something simple to make sure your connections are correct and get outputs from a table, then you can expand your program and functionalities.

Comment: the queryString  should be
"SELECT * FROM [yourDBNameHere]

Comment: Try opening your connection first then make then have this line `OdbcDataAdapter adapter =   new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection);`

Comment: I can open the connection but I think the actual query string is incorrect.
I'm getting Unknown Table errors. Is there a way to display the tables? connection.GetScheme("Tables") doesn't work. 
I've added database=ADI